# Как сравнить две даты с точностью до минут?

Tags: c#

Есть две переменные, которые хранят значение типа DateTime. Как можно сравнить на равенство взяв к учету только часы и минуты.  Кроме этого варианта:

```
date1.Hours == date2.Hours &&
date1.Minutes == date2.Minutes
```

Comment: `10:10:59` и `10:11:01` должны быть равны (между ними куда как меньше минуты) или нет (количество целых минут не равно)?

Comment: Не равны. Да, количество целых минут.

Comment: По сути разница в минутах между двумя датами решит мою проблему.

Comment: Кроме этого варианта, можно этот вариант оформить в виде функции `int сравнить_до_минут(Date a, Date b)`, и используя эту функцию `if (сравнить_до_минут(date1, date2) < 0) ...`, более не беспокоиться о безобразном виде условия`:)`

Comment: Здесь метод для обрезки удобный: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1005222/6766879

Comment: Ну вот как надо мыслить, чтобы выдать подряд два взаимоисключающих комментария-ответа?

Comment: @АлександрПузанов, год/месяц/день могут быть разные? Или важно только время с начала суток?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Int64 t1 = (Int64) TimeSpan.FromTicks(date1.Ticks).TotalMinutes;
Int64 t2 = (Int64) TimeSpan.FromTicks(date2.Ticks).TotalMinutes;
return t1 == t2;
```

Answer (score 7):

Если разница между датами в минутах решает проблему - то вот код:

```
Math.Abs((date1 - date2).TotalMinutes) < 1
```

Но такое сравнение дат будет нетранзитивным: 00:00:10 будет равно 00:00:40, а 00:00:40 будет равно 00:01:10 - но 00:00:10 не равно 00:01:10.

Для сохранения транзитивности лучше все же отбросить младшие части даты:

```
DateTime TruncateToMinutes(DateTime date) => new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, date.Hour, date.Minute, 0);

TruncateToMinutes(date1) == TruncateToMinutes(date2);
```

Answer (score -1):

Можете преобразовать обе переменные типа DateTime к Unix Timestamp, например, как показано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354893/how-can-i-convert-a-datetime-to-the-number-of-seconds-since-1970), использовав только часы и минуты, как вы и хотите, а далее сравнить 2 получившихся Timestamp.